The book regarding Rama Upasana
Suggest any traditional and non-traditional book which dealing with Rama Upasana.

I can suggest books 1 for Rama and 1 for Upanasana but both are separate books

You can look at the Rama-Tapaniya Upanishad and the Rama Rahasya Upanishad. They are both from the 108 Upanishads, and may help you.

It is upanishad for Upasana book

@PashamVishnuVardhanGoud Please go through those Upanishads. They are mantropanishads and deal primarily with mantras and upasana of the deity. The same thing goes for Gopala-Tapani Upanishad, Nrisimha-Tapani etc.
There are mantropanishads, yogopanishads etc., apart from the rest. There are many categories among the 108 Upanishads.
